# How can i run the same WordPress install on multiple subdomains?

Tags: subdomains, woocommerce-offtopic, domain, domain-mapping

My site is installed on my main domain, lets say something.com for an example. I have WooCommerce installed and i would like to run the shop part of the site on store.something.com with the same WordPress install. Also, the blog would run on blog.something.com.

I think Multisite is not what i'm after based on the "Before You Create A Network" article in the Codex.

Is it possible to do this without installing multiple Wordpress on the subdomains?

Comment: If you want to run on subdomains, multisite really is your only option. An existing site can survive the switch to multisite, just make sure to back everything up.

Comment: Why do you think that multisite is not what you want?  It does what you want but is more complex.

Comment: Multisite _does not_ install WordPress multiple times (from your question). But _"If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that share data, or share users, then a multisite network might not be the best solution."_ tells us the exact opposite. Please [edit] your question and clarify your needs.

Answer (score 2):

WP multisite (subdomain) is the answer - http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

In addition you can install the [WP Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to run on other domains

You need to decide whether you want WP multisite subdomain or sub-directory installation. WP subdomain does exactly what you want, but WP subdir + domain mapping plugin allows you to have both (subdomain AND sub-directory). WP subdomain looks like this:
domain.com (main site)
site1.domain.com
site2.domain.com

WP subdirectory looks like this:
domain.com (main site)
domain.com/site1
domain.com/site2

With WP Domain Mapping plugin you can map any subsite above to another domain, for example:
site1.domain.com -> www.site1.com
site2.domain.com -> www.site2.com
[or]
domain.com/site1 -> www.site1.com
domain.com/site2 -> www.site2.com

Comment: "If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that share data, or share users, then a multisite network might not be the best solution." Thats why i think Multisite is not what i'm looking for, copied from the codex.

Comment: You do not provide enough information to know if that applies to your situation.  I do not think it is possible for a single WP site to host multiple domains... so either WP multisite or multiple WP single sites are your options.

Comment: @user42826 the OP actually provided perfectly clear information that they want to run all on *the same wordpress install*. your answer, albeit having good intentions, ignores the OP

Answer (score 1):

@passatgt, make some edit in your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); 
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/plug/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

after this edition you will see a 'Network Setup' option under 'Tools' menu in your wordpress dashboard. Follow the instruction you will be directed. edit your '.htaccess' file in wordpress and finally you will be able to set multisite in your wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this without installing multiple WordPress on the subdomains.

Unfortunately the answer is: no. It's not possible to route various domains to different content nodes within *one WordPress site*. The reason is that WordPress handles URLs internally as constants (e.g. `WP_CONTENT_URL` which is build of to the `siteurl` option). So once they are set up, they can't be changed any more.

So even if there would be a really theoretical way, it would mean that you have to hack around every part that uses the constant `WP_CONTENT_URL`. I don't think that this is a reliable way.

Long story short, WordPress is not designed to deal with multiple host names within a single site. The only way to do that is the multisite feature. In fact, multisite is the hack that overcomes the issues with the constants by implementing a »sunrise« process that defines the constants according to a list of valid hosts in a database table (`wp_blogs`).